# Alter oracle Regex to accept email domains with hyphen '-'

Tags: regex, oracle, email, dns

I've been using the regexp blow to check email validation in Oracle SQL Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE
   REGEXP_LIKE(
         EMAIL,
         '^('
           -- Unquoted local-part
           || '[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*'
           --                               ^^
           --                               Allow a dot but always expect a
           --                               non-dot after it.
           -- Quoted local-part
           || '|"('
             -- Unescaped characters in the quotes
             || '[]' || CHR(1) || '-' || CHR(8) || CHR(11) || CHR(12) || CHR(14) || '-!#-[^-'||CHR(127)||']'
             -- Escaped characters in the quotes
             || '|\\[' || CHR(1) || '-' || CHR(9) || CHR(11) || CHR(12) || CHR(14) || '-' || CHR(127) || ']'
             || ')*"'
           || ')'
           -- Match at symbol at end of local-part
           || '@'
           --Domain Part
           ||'(([A-Z0-9]{1,63})[A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$',
           -- Case insensitive
           'i'
   )
```

'**t-online.de**' is a valid top domain level address. How can I change the regex domain part below, to accept the RFC5322 that says '**hyphen - is valid, provided that it is not the first or last character**'.

```
'(([A-Z0-9]{1,63})[A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$
```

Thank you all

Comment: Why asking twice the same  question?

Comment: I recieved a confirmation on the first one that the question was closed, to be more specific.

Comment: Then update the other and ask for reopen.

Comment: It is possible to delete all my questions posted today, please?
I would prefer to place them separately to keep the focus.